# Focus input of freshly added item

Tags: vue.js

So I have a list of items and list of inputs linked to each item via v-for and v-model.

I click a button and add new item to that list. I want to focus input which is linked to newly added item.

Can't figure out how to achieve this goal.

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in sortedItems">
    <input v-model="item">
  </div>
  <button @click="addItem">
    add
  </button>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function() {
      this.items.push(Math.random());
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sortedItems: function() {
      return this.items.sort(function(i1, i2) {
        return i1 - i2;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Here's fiddle with sorted list
https://jsfiddle.net/sfL91r95/1/

Thanks

Comment: Check the docs on [**Custom Directives**](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) which uses `v-focus` as an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: inspired by pkawiak's comment, a directive-based solution. I found that calling `focus` in the `bind` section didn't work; I had to use `nextTick` to delay it.

```js
Vue.directive('focus-on-create', {
  // Note: using Vue 1. In Vue 2, el would be a parameter
  bind: function() {
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      this.el.focus();
    })
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function() {
      this.items.push(Math.random());
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sortedItems: function() {
      return this.items.sort(function(i1, i2) {
        return i1 - i2;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in sortedItems">
    <input v-focus-on-create v-model="item">
  </div>
  <button @click="addItem">
    add
  </button>
</div>
```

Original answer:
Make your input a component so that you can give it [a `ready` hook](http://vuejs.org/api/#ready).

```js
const autofocus = Vue.extend({
  template: '<input v-model="item" />',
  props: ['item'],
  ready: function() {
    this.$el.focus();
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function() {
      this.items.push(Math.random());
    }
  },
  components: {
    autofocus
  },
  computed: {
    sortedItems: function() {
      return this.items.sort(function(i1, i2) {
        return i1 - i2;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in sortedItems">
    <autofocus :item="item"></autofocus>
  </div>
  <button @click="addItem">
    add
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd say that it's the cleanest way. The only drawback is that using component is a bit heavier than simple markup. But  'premature optimization is evil' I guess that you could also try directive for more lightweight approach. Anyway +1

Comment: @pkawiak I agree, a directive is a better idea. Answer updated. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Thanks alot.

Comment: `this.el` is undefined now. Instead have `bind: function(el)` and use that `el`

Comment: @Zout True for Vue 2, but the answer was for Vue 1, where things were in `this`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much - that's what I meant by "undefined now" :)

Answer (score 1):

I Like to extend **@Roy**'s answer.
if you are using any UI framework then it will create DIV and within the DIV input tag will be created so this Snippet will handle that case.

```
Vue.directive('focus-on-create', { 
    bind: function(el) { 
          Vue.nextTick(() => { 
              el.querySelector('input').focus()
          })
    }
})
```